# Search results heading and counter not working - Oxygen Builder

Tags: search

this code was inserted using the Code Block component on Oxygen Builder and it should render a heading and the results counter.

```
<h1 class="woo-pages-title">Search Results: "<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" &mdash; <?php $allsearch = new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=0"); 
echo $allsearch ->found_posts.' items.'; ?></h1>
```

It should render something like:

> Search Results: "flour" — 2 items

At first, this was working correctly, but now it shows me this error:

> Search Results: "flour" —
> Warning: Undefined variable $s in /home/sgajdosik/webapps/Wholeness-DEV/wp-content/plugins/oxygen/component-framework/components/classes/code-block.class.php(133) : eval()'d code on line 1
> 125 items.

Can you please help me to correct this code?